# Why when I push the start button on my computer it starts the components running only?

Tags: boot, troubleshooting

Why when I push the start button on my computer it starts the components running, but I have to push it again to boot system start up. I started doing this out of the blue. It happens with any opperating system.

Do you think it is a BIOS thing?

Comment: So, do you mean you have to press the power button twice to turn the computer on?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your bios settings. Look for a hard drive startup delay which could be causing your issue and if it's short trying make the start delay longer to see if that resolves the issue. Also have you checked your power supply unit? You want many to test your system with a known good power supply and see if that resolves your issue.